# TextView, get the right-side X coordinate of a character

Tags: android, textview

Let's say that I want to get the bounds of a character, of which I know the offset. I can get the left X coordinate with `getPrimaryHorizontal`; I can get the top Y/bottom Y coordinate by getting the line number, and then `getLineBounds`. The line bounds seem to fill the entire screen width, even if there is empty space at the end.

I tried to use the next character's left X coordinate, but it is problematic when the current character happens to be the last character in the line. Is there a better solution?

[image]

Comment: Try `getLineRight(0)`.

Comment: @Cheticamp Thanks.